# Replace specific <font> tag with <span> using DOM manipulation in PHP

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I'm trying to replace all  tags with  tags using DOMDocument in PHP and almost all my tests passed. I'm sure there are other scenarios I'm forgetting, but for now, I'm missing just one:

**ORIGINAL:**

```
<p><font color="#ff0000">BEFORE <font color="#00ff00">BEFORE <font color="#0000ff">VAL</font> AFTER</font> AFTER</font></p>
```

**RESULT:**

```
<p><span style="color: #ff0000">BEFORE BEFORE VAL AFTER AFTER</span></p>
```

The PHP code for this:

```
$html = '<p><font color="#ff0000">BEFORE <font color="#00ff00">BEFORE <font color="#0000ff">VAL</font> AFTER</font> AFTER</font></p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('font') as $node) {
    $font_nodes[] = $node;
}

//$font_nodes = array_reverse($font_nodes);

foreach($font_nodes as $font) {
    $a_style = array_filter(explode(';', $font->getAttribute('style')));

    if($a_color = $font->getAttribute('color')) {
        $a_style[] = 'color: '.$a_color;
    }

    $span = $dom->createElement('span', $font->nodeValue);
    $span->setAttribute('style', implode('; ', $a_style));

    $font->parentNode->replaceChild($span, $font);
}

echo preg_replace("#(<!DOCTYPE.+|<\/?html>|<\/?body>)#", '', $dom->saveHTML());
```

I thought that `getElementsByTagName` was the culprit since it was loading the nodes in order, so I tried to start from the deepest tag by reversing the array, but that didn't work so the line is commented.

P.S: In case you're wondering why the first loop is needed to save all the nodes and loop them again, please read this: http://robrosenbaum.com/php/domnodelist-gotchas/

Comment: If you could include the output, that may be helpful...

Comment: It's there since I posted this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This works. I tested it. :-)**

Replace the line:

```
$span = $dom->createElement('span', $font->nodeValue);
```

With this:

```
$span = $dom->createElement('span');
$children = array(); 
foreach ($font->childNodes as $child) $children[] = $child;
foreach ($children as $child) $span->appendChild($child);
```

Comment: I don't have access to a system with php 5... :P

Comment: I was doing something similar but only with one loop, forgetting why I had 2 for the `<font>` tag in the first place. The issue I was having was the same. Thanks.

Comment: I've rewarded you with a vote for a technically correct answer, but will at the same time give a gentle critique.  A good answer should explain the problem and help people learn, not just supply code.

Comment: @jswolf19 I can't imagine living without PHP5. Get a Mac! @leeeb I'm teaching by example. :-P

Comment: If a pupil passed an exam by copying a sheet with the answers, would that be learning by example? Now take the advice with good grace, or I'll be mean and take away my vote!

Comment: @leeeb LOL. Don't be mean! I voted for your answer, after all, and why should I re-write your great explanation? ....passing an exam has little to do with learning, by the way.... In my opinion, learning depends on the will and actions of the student.

Answer (score 1):

When you call replaceChild, the child nodes of the font element remain attached to the removed node, rather than become attached to the new span element.  The font elements are all individually being replaced, but they're no longer attached to the rest of the dom elements.  This is why your visible output ends at the top level span element, which is empty.

To solve this, you will need to add a few extra lines of code to copy all of the child nodes from $font to $span after replaceNode.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure:

```
$font->parentNode->replaceChild($span, $font);
```

is your culprit because the nested elements' parents are no longer in the document. You were on the right track trying to reverse the order, but when you reversed, you overwrote your changes because you were using a copy of the parent font that still included the child font. **I don't have a system I can test on**, but I imagine code like this will do what you want it to:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$font_nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('font');
while($font = $font_nodes->item(0)) {
    $a_style = array_filter(explode(';', $font->getAttribute('style')));

    if($a_color = $font->getAttribute('color')) {
        $a_style[] = 'color: '.$a_color;
    }

    $span = $dom->createElement('span', $font->nodeValue);
    $span->setAttribute('style', implode('; ', $a_style));

    $font->parentNode->replaceChild($span, $font);

    $font_nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('font');
}
```

Comment: I get this on the while `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[`, and I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: @Nazgulled, sorry, php doesn't like accessing arrays directly from the return of the function... Try the edited code

Comment: Nope, still a no go `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array`

Comment: @Nazgulled, sorry, I was looking at the PHP4 docs that said `getElementsByTagName` returns an array... ^^; You probably already have an acceptable answer by now, anyway ^_^

Comment: Still, if your solution worked, it would be more compact. No errors now, but it didn't quite work, here's the result: `<p><span style="color: #ff0000">BEFORE </span><span style="color: #00ff00">BEFORE </span><span style="color: #0000ff">VAL</span> AFTER AFTER</p>`. It missed the last two words...

Comment: @Nazgulled, the nesting isn't working properly for some reason... I wonder if `textContent` would work instead of `nodeValue`...

Comment: Actually your code is giving me just this:`<p><span style="color: #ff0000">BEFORE BEFORE VAL AFTER AFTER</span></p>
`. Using `textContent` didn't help. The previous result was a different test with another problem, never mind that.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, if it worked I would prefer it because it was simpler but no need to make it work anymore. Because my problem now requires a different approach to this issue. You see, I'm doing a WordPress plugin which fixes the code posted by Windows Live Writer, that's why I was removing the font tags and replacing them with span tags. However, some WP filter (one that tries to fix nested XHTML tags) was messing the font tags markup because it does not recognize them and no matter the code of my plugin, the markup would never be right one. I'm doing this a little differently now.